# Why traversal on modified 'std::vector' more slowly than unmodified 'std::vector'?

Tags: c++

This is the code that shows the access behavior of `std::vector` slows down when `std::vector` is sorted by `std::sort()`.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr auto NUM_KEYS(24000000);
constexpr auto CLOCK_MILI(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
constexpr auto CHARS("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

static int x = 0;

void insert(void* obj) {
  std::size_t len = std::strlen((const char*)obj);
  for(std::size_t i=0; i<len; ++i)
    for(std::size_t j=0; j<len; ++j)
      ++x;
}

int main(void) {
  std::vector<void*> list;
  auto seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  std::mt19937_64 rng(seed);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rand_ch(0, 25);
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> rand_len(8, 16);

  // Generate random string
  for(std::size_t i=0; i<NUM_KEYS; ++i) {
    std::size_t len = rand_len(rng);
    char* buf = new char[len+1]();
    for(std::size_t j=0; j<len; ++j)
      buf[j] = CHARS[rand_ch(rng)];
    list.push_back(buf);
  }

  // First traverse the list
  std::clock_t cl = std::clock();
  for(auto obj : list)
    insert(obj);
  printf("Time 1 = %ld miliseconds\n", (clock()-cl)/CLOCK_MILI);

  // Sorting the list
  std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(),
    [](const void* a, const void* b) {
      return std::strcmp((const char*)a, (const char*)b)<0;
    });
  
  // Second traverse the list
  cl = std::clock();
  for(auto obj : list)
    insert(obj);
  printf("Time 2 = %ld miliseconds\n", (clock()-cl)/CLOCK_MILI);

  // Destroy the strings
  for(auto obj : list)
    delete[] (char*)obj;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There are 2 iterations trying to traverse the `list` while calling `insert()`. The `insert()` function does not modify the data. The first iteration is done without `std::sort()`, and the second iteration is done after `std::sort()`.

The result obtained at runtime executed on option `-std=c++17 -O3` with GCC 11.1.0:

```
Time 1 = 101 miliseconds
Time 2 = 909 miliseconds
```

Likewise, the result when `std::sort()` is omitted at run:

```
Time 1 = 102 miliseconds
Time 2 = 101 miliseconds
```

Access to `list` is 9 times slower when `list` is modified by `std::sort()`. Similar results occur when `std::sort()` is replaced with `std::random_shuffle()`, or some code that modifies `list`.

- So what really happened?
- Why does traversal of `std::vector` slow down after modification?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but GCC appears to be optimizing `insert(obj)` into the equivalent of `len = strlen(obj); x += len * len;`.  https://godbolt.org/z/8WeG9fYrT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selection of the vector name is accidentally quite revealing. Because the vector is a vector of pointers, it behaves similarly to a list, causing data that was originally allocated in (probably) linear order to be accessed after sorting in random order.
If in contrast all the data you access is contained within the vector without indirection, I would expect the runtimes being much closer in each run.

The cause of this phenomenom is cache misprediction or that the data to be read next not being available in the smallest/fastest data cache. Reading data from main memory or deeper levels of cache is typically orders of magnitude slower than reading them from the top level cache and the sorting will invalidate all chances of predicting the next memory addresses to read.

Comment: I didn't realize that `new` would allocate contiguous memory, while `std::sort` causes vector elements to scatter randomly. Thank you for the answer.